# System.asserts for testing Apex controller class with Current User

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, user

This could be pretty straight forward, but I am not sure what arguments I need to pass for comparison within System.asserts(I don't know if I really need to have asserts in my test method). Thing is, I already got **100%** code coverage for my controller class. But I still doubt that I might require to use System.asserts.

Controller class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static User getUser() {
    User currentUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        return currentUser;
```

Comment: This could fall under the "covered with other tests" category (if done properly) but since aura enabled you will need to write a test for it yes. And yes, you absolutely need asserts. Without them you are not testing anything except that your code does not throw an uncaught error. It could be sending messages to the NSA for all you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass any arguments. The test should simply look like:

```
static testmethod void testGetUser()
{
    Test.startTest();
        User currentUser = MyClass.getUser();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(null, currentUser,
        'A User record should be returned');
    system.assertEquals(UserInfo.getUserId(), currentUser.Id,
        'The correct User should be returned');
    // if you care about which fields are queried as an implementation detail:
    system.assertEquals(UserInfo.getName(), currentUser.Name,
        'The Name field should be queried');
}
```